# Problem with locating template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to install django lfc on my server. Apart of zilions of different problems I've encountered now I'm struggling with `TemplateDoesNotExist`.
In my settings file I have set TEMPLATE_DIRS variable like this :

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                "/home/snow4life/lfc/templates",
                "/home/snow4life/lfc_theme/templates"
                "/home/snow4life/lfc_blog/templates"
)
```

and it corresponds to my files structure. Still when I'm trying to run the application I'm getting TemplateDoesNotExist exception when one of the templates loads `{% templates %}` templatetag which looks as follows :

```
@register.inclusion_tag('lfc/manage/templates.html', takes_context=True)
def templates(context):
    (...)
```

So it should load template from `/lfc/templates/lfc/manage/templates.html` but instead reads only `lfc/manage/templates.html` just as it would skip the first folder from the settings. Any ideas how to resolve this ? I'm using the latest django buildout from trunk. Tell me if I should post more info cuz I'm not sure what might be needed.

Comment: after reinstallation and setting django version to 1.2.3 everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Django installation.